# How would i make a circular graph in c#?

Tags: c#, animation, graph

hello I am making an application that the design requires special graphs that change depending on the value that is give. like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

how would i go about doing this? could someone point me in the right direction?
the outer ring of the orange changes with the value but the middle circle stays static.

p.s my paint skills are amazing.

Comment: That would be a circular graph. Spheres are three dimensional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can draw your own control quite easily. The main thing is the `FillPie` method, which draws only part of a circle. To change the starting point of the outer ring or the filling direction you need to change the starting and sweep angle in the `FillPie` call of the `OnPaint` event.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

public class CircularProgressBar : Control
{

    #region "Properties"
    private Color _BorderColor;
    public Color BorderColor
    {
        get { return _BorderColor; }
        set
        {
            _BorderColor = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private Color _InnerColor;
    public Color InnerColor
    {
        get { return _InnerColor; }
        set
        {
            _InnerColor = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private bool _ShowPercentage;
    public bool ShowPercentage
    {
        get { return _ShowPercentage; }
        set
        {
            _ShowPercentage = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private int _BorderWidth;
    public int BorderWidth
    {
        get { return _BorderWidth; }
        set
        {
            _BorderWidth = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private float _Value;
    public float Value
    {
        get { return _Value; }
        set
        {
            _Value = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region "Constructor"
    public CircularProgressBar()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        _Value = 100;
        _BorderColor = Color.Orange;
        _BorderWidth = 30;
        _ShowPercentage = true;
        _InnerColor = Color.DarkGray;
        this.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
    #endregion

    #region "Painting"
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        //Measure the single parts
        int Diameter = Math.Min(this.ClientSize.Width, this.ClientSize.Height);
        int InnerDiameter = Diameter - BorderWidth;
        Rectangle PieRect = new Rectangle(Convert.ToInt32(this.ClientSize.Width / 2 - Diameter / 2), Convert.ToInt32(this.ClientSize.Height / 2 - Diameter / 2), Diameter, Diameter);
        Rectangle InnerRect = new Rectangle(Convert.ToInt32(this.ClientSize.Width / 2 - InnerDiameter / 2), Convert.ToInt32(this.ClientSize.Height / 2 - InnerDiameter / 2), InnerDiameter, InnerDiameter);

        //Draw outer ring
        using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(BorderColor))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillPie(b, PieRect, 0, Value / 100 * 360);
        }

        //Draw inner ring
        using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(this._InnerColor))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(b, InnerRect);
        }

        //Draw percentage
        if (ShowPercentage)
        {
            using (StringFormat sf = new StringFormat())
            {
                sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor))
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(Convert.ToInt32(Value).ToString() + "%", this.Font, b, InnerRect, sf);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

}
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: This is nice! A simple DrawArc would do, too. But this is cool!

Comment: @user3379346 Just add the class to your project and compile. Then you will find the control in your toolbox, just like any other control. Change the value property from 0-100 to adjust the arc. Forecolor and font define how the inner number is drawn.

Comment: thanks for your help i really appreciate it. i have one more question. out could i have it so it refreshes say every .5 of a second?

Comment: Why would you do that? The control will be redrawn whenever something changes, there is no need to do that yourself. If you want you can add a timer to your form and in the tick event call Refresh on the graph, but that's a weird thing to do.

Comment: when i change the value. the value on the form does not change. hence why i thought i would need to refresh it.

Comment: It does. Are you sure that you are inputting the correct value, and not, for example a percentage value between 0-1, instead of 0-100?

Comment: i input a value to the variable to _Value

Comment: No, why would you do this. That variable is private for a reason. Use the `Value` property. Just use the control like you would use a `ProgressBar`.